# Java | static vars in parent and child class | accessing the child var value from parent class

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, static, overwrite

i have a few sub classes with unique static vars in this case called 'x'.
All of those sub classes are using the static var the same way, so I want to reduce code duplication and put the functionality in the super class. 
In this case the method 'getX' in the super class. From here I want to return the value of x. Right now I'm facing the issue that it uses the x value of the super class and not the value of the child class. How can I access the x value of the sub class from the super class?

```
public class Playground {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    Child child = new Child();
    Child1 child1 = new Child1();

    System.out.println("Parent.x " + parent.x);
    System.out.println("child.x " + child.x);
    System.out.println("child.x " + child1.x);

    System.out.println("get x: " + parent.getX());
    System.out.println("get x: " + child.getX());
  }
}

class Parent {
  static String x = "static of parent";
  String y = "instance of parent";

  String getX() {
      return x;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static String x = "static of child";
  String y = "instance of child";
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  static String x = "static of child1";
  String y = "instance of child";
}
```

This code prints out:
`Parent.x static of parent
 child.x static of child
 child.x static of child1
 get x: static of parent
 get x: static of parent` **<-- here should be static of child**

Hope someone can help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the getX method to the child. Like this:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  static String x = "static of child";
  String y = "instance of child";
  String getX() {
      return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: In my real scenario I have 6 sub classes, so I don't want to copy getX which are 3-4 methods (in the real scenario) in all sub classes

Comment: But when you call the getX method, java calls the one from Parent. That's why you're getting the x from parent. I think this is the only way to get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to not have a static in the Parent, but an instance field.

```
class Parent{
    private final X x
    public Parent(X x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public X getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Then in your child, you still can have a static, but you pass it at the constructor

```
class Child extends Parent {
    static final X x = ....
    public Child() {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the getX method in the child class.
The parent getX method points to the static variable of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is a violation of the basic OOP principle *information hiding* / *encapulation*.

No other class should know about how a class stores or treats its properties (aka *variables* or *fields*). This includes that clases should not have *getter* and *setter* (as suggested by @RosárioPereiraFernandes)

There is an exception to this rule when the class represents a *data transfer object* (DTO) which has (almost) no business logic and just provides access to structured data. DTOs shoould have *getters* and (less often) *setters*.

Other classes should provide methods with busines related names to modify their inner state (the values of their member variables):

```
class Car{
  private final int maxSpeedInMph = 100;
  private int speedInMph = 0;
  public void accellerateBy(int speedDiffInMph){
    if( maxSpeedInMph >=speedInMph + speedDiffInMph )
       speedInMph += speedDiffInMph;
    else 
       speedInMph = maxSpeedInMph ;
  }    
  public void accellerateTo(int newSpeedInMph){
    if( maxSpeedInMph >=  newSpeedInMph)
       speedInMph = newSpeedInMph;
    else 
       speedInMph = maxSpeedInMph ;
  }
  public void decellerateBy(int speedDiffInMph){
    if( 0<=speedInMph - speedDiffInMph )
       speedInMph += speedDiffInMph;
    else 
       speedInMph = 0;
  }
  public void emengencyBreak(){
    speedInMph = 0;
  }
  // you get the idea?
}
```

Comment: I get that, I my case each child has a unique constant which I want to use. There is no manipulation. Think about a Bank with different types of BankAccounts and each type of BankAccount has a constant BankFee. So I want to have a method that returns the BankFee for each BankAccount without going into each child BankAccount and add a getter which returns the types BankFee.

Comment: @DΦC__WTF : *" I my case each child has a unique constant which I want to use"* Why? - Most likely you plan to use it in `swich` statements. But you should rather use *plymorphism* to do specific actions based on a classes type.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to access child-variables from the parent-class.

But you can override `String getX()` in the child class

```
@Override
protected String getX() {        
    return x;
}
```

Then Java calls the "lowest" `getX()`method

---

I would code your example different:

```
public class Playground {

private static Parent parent = new Parent("static of parent");
private static Child child = new Child("static of child");
private static Child1 child1 = new Child1("static of child1");

  public class Playground {

private static Parent parent = new Parent("static of parent");
private static Child child = new Child("static of child");
private static Child child1 = new Child("static of child1");

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Parent.x " + parent.getX());
    System.out.println("child.x " + child.getX());
    System.out.println("child.x " + child1.getX());

    System.out.println("get x: " + parent.getX());
    System.out.println("get x: " + child.getX());
  }
}

 class Parent {
     private String x;
     public Parent(String x) {
         this.x = x;

     }

     public String getX() {
          return this.x;
      }
 }

class Child extends Parent {
    protected Child(String x) {
        super(x);
    }  
}
```

-> this will bring the following output:

```
Parent.x static of parent
child.x static of child
child.x static of child1
get x: static of parent
get x: static of child
```

Just ask if you have questions