# Examples/Use-cases of design in which parent class accesses its child's static field

Tags: java, inheritance, static, parent-child

**EDIT :** The [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215497/7804477) **DOES NOT** answer this question as it is about **HOW** it is accessible. But my question is **when** should such a design be used or any examples of such a design.

**NOTE : Anyone looking for an answer to this question can scroll down in the comment section to see Thomas's comments in the end related to `java.lang.CharacterData`**.

---

Some of the questions with a similar title actually discuss the usage of static variables with the same name in child and parent. example: [Java | static vars in parent and child class | accessing the child var value from parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505611/java-static-vars-in-parent-and-child-class-accessing-the-child-var-value-fro)

But my question is regarding the purpose of accessing child's static field in parent class.

```java
class Child extends Parent {
    static String someString = "test";
}

class Parent {
    void someMethod() {
        System.out.println(Child.someString);
    }
}
```

Isn't this a bad design? Ideally, if `someString` is required in `Parent`, then it should be a field in `Parent` instead of `Child`.

Are there any use-cases/examples when this approach could be used?

Comment: I agree with you, this **is** bad design. But why should java specifically not allow accessing a public static field of a subclass (when it allows accessing public static fields of all other classes?)

Comment: False premise. Java doesn't let you do that necessarily. Default access is package private (in this case, anyway; the defaults vary a bit with context), which these 2 classes presumably are. The inheritance aspect of this is not relevant.

Comment: @ThomasKläger but why should I be declaring a static variable in the child class if it is to be used in the parent?

Comment: If you don't want it to be used outside of the class in which it's declared, make it private.

Comment: Maybe the child is the primary implementation of a parent.  That's a pretty common thing.

Comment: @ThomasKläger "*But why should java specifically not allow accessing a **public** static field of a subclass*". It's not public.

Comment: @Michael Louis's comment might be one use case. `Child` and `Parent` are in the same package, but if I do not want `someString` to be accessible to other subclasses (which are in a different package) this could be used right? But still it would be the same as declaring a default field in `Parent` ?

Comment: There is a table in the linked duplicate which shows the access for subclasses, both in the same package and different packages.

Comment: @Michael The linked duplicate is about "how" the field is accessible. My question is "when should" accessing a child's static field in parent be used.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. Opinion-based questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Michael yes it is kind of opinion based but not a duplicate :-)

Comment: I agree that the duplicate doesn't answer the question, but if it's off topic anyway then there's no point reopening it.

Comment: I have finally an example where this pattern is used (it's even in the JDK): the class `java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1` extends `java.lang.CharacterData` and has a field `static final CharacterDataLatin1 instance = new CharacterDataLatin1();` that is used from [`java.lang.CharacterData.of()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/CharacterData.java#L79).

Comment: Here the parent class `CharacterData` delegates some of it's work to subclasses that are only loaded if they are needed.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Great! Looks like this pattern is good to use when singleton child classes are involved.

Comment: I have to change my first comment: this can be bad design. But it can also be useful for example if a parent class contains a factory method that returns singleton-instances of one of several subclasses. And then: why should java specifically enforce stricter access rules from a parent class to a subclass's fields than from other classes to those same fields?

Comment: @ThomasKläger My initial phrasing of the question `"Why does Java allow..."` was actually confusing, my intention was to know the use-cases of such a pattern rather than asking "why does this work". I have edited the title. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Thomas's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537352/examples-use-cases-of-design-in-which-parent-class-accesses-its-childs-static-f#comment119377173_67537352):

This pattern could be used to return a specific implementation from a method in the parent class. i.e it is useful when a parent class contains a static factory method that returns singleton-instance of one of several subclasses.

An example available within the JDK is `java.lang.CharacterData`. This is an abstract class which is extended by 8 other classes (`CharacterData00`, `CharacterData01`, ...) All these implementing classes are **non-public and singleton** and hence contains a `static final instance` variable. Since these implementations are non-public (default access), it is not supposed to be accessed directly. So, the `CharacterData` contains a static factory method `of`, which returns the appropriate implementation.